# What WPF control should i use for my window?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

So im making a WPF project where one of my windows has to let the user see a text. Select parts of this text for being put into an array of strings and no more than that. So he/she musnt be able to edit anything in the text only highlight parts and then click on a button. What WPF control would be smart to use for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd probably just use `TextBox` with `IsReadOnly` set. The various selection properties are all you need after that.